# Universal Date Parser?

Tags: php, regex, date, format

I am passing a list of values to a function to convert to and from specific type of values. For example, if a PHP Date is passed, or a timestamp is passed, I want to convert to a specific date format. Here is the code I have now:

```
    public static function attemptParseString($str) {
        $check = strtotime($str);
        if ($check !== FALSE) {
            return date(ts_default_date_format, $check).' <span class="grey">(Orig: '.$str.')</span>';
        }
        $check = date(ts_default_date_format, $str);
        if ($check !== FALSE) {
            return $check.' <span class="grey">(Orig: '.$str.')</span>';
        }
        return $str;
    }
```

Most date values (like '1361215542' and '2013-02-18 13:25:42') return as expected, but I get some weird issues with things like '127.0.0.1' parsing as '1969-12-31 18:02:07', 'GET' parsing as '2013-02-18 04:25:42' and '80' parsing as '1969-12-31 18:01:20'.

How can I intelligently decide whether a string is a valid date, besides checking if the date function parses it as a date?

Ive seen similar questions, like the following, but they weren't quite right (some were a different programming language, and some contained all valid dates but in different formats [whereas I contain dates and non date strings).

[Problem getting date with Universal Feed Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022504/problem-getting-date-with-universal-feed-parser)
[Date parser for all formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742323/date-parser-for-all-formats)
[Unexpected result from Date() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514034/unexpected-result-from-date-function)

Thanks!

Comment: Use a regular expression for check whether or not the string is a date

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction to a rather comprehensive REGEX to do this? Again, I do not know the format coming in and want to catch as many as I can.

Comment: You firstly have to define a list of ALL possible formats. Then use preg_match() to check all patterns you made in the 1st point. And finally — parse date depends on which pattern matched.

Comment: That's part of my problem. I don't have a list of all the possible date formats. I just need to know whether it is a date or not. If there is no "universal" regex, can you point me to a few of them that covers most use cases?

Comment: I'm not sure, but personally never heard about such regex. By the way it is wrong way if you want to accept a lot of different patterns when you don't even have a complete list of them, this is what I guess.

Comment: Yes, it is not what I prefer. However, it is necessary since we do not control the data coming in, but do control how it is going out. Any ideas?

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) - there are a few interesting solutions in the comments on the bottom.